# Magnetization and thermodynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, magnetic-fields

A magnetic needle is placed such that the magnetic field is parallel to its axis. I need to prove the following relation between the specific capacities where $M$ is the magnetization and H the magnetic field:
$$ C_H = C_M + \left[\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial M}\right)_{T} - H\right]\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}\right)_{H}.$$ The work done to increase the magnetization is given by $\text dW = H\,\text dM.$

Do you have any suggestion for solving the problem? Thanks

Comment: [Many relations between heat capacities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relations_between_heat_capacities#Derivation) can be obtained by expanding $dS$ as $dS=(dS/dT)_XdT+(dS/dX)_TdX$ and then differentiating with respect to $T$ while keeping $Y$ constant, where $X$ and $Y$ are state variables of interest. Importantly, that gives you $(dS/dT)_X$ and $(dS/dT)_Y$, which are related to $C_X$ and $C_Y$, respectively.